# React-Redux cross module communication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, model-view-controller, redux

What is the right way to setup cross module communication in React Redux?

Suppose there is a use case where on some action, I would need updates to take place to multiple modules.  Where should the code for this go?

Example 1: Module A controls actions for View A and Module B for View B.  On clicking a link in Module B, I need to dispatch some actions to both Module A and Module B.

Alternately, if there is a use case, where I need to dispatch an action from either Module A or Module B, but there is some action in both Module A and Module B that needs to take place.

How should I design my application so it can handle it correctly and cleanly?  (I'm using Ducks pattern of code arrangement for my application where modules consist of actions + reducers + action creators)

Comment: what do you mean by _"I want to take users to View A"_ ? do you mean routing? anyway if both modules or thier parents are connected to the `redux` store then you will receive the new data after dispatching the actions and returning the new state from the `reducers` .

Comment: Right the state changes will happen through reducers... But suppose I need to update states in both modules A and B.  Where should I dispatch these actions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the reasons why I'm not a fan of the "ducks" pattern conceptually.  Quoting my post [The Tao of Redux, Part 2 - Practice and Philosophy](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/05/idiomatic-redux-tao-of-redux-part-2/):

> To me, there are a couple conceptual downsides to the "ducks" pattern. One is that it guides you away from the idea of multiple slice reducers independently responding to the same action. Nothing about "ducks" prevents you from having multiple reducers respond, but having everything in one file somewhat suggests that it's all self-contained and not as likely to interact with other parts of the system. There's also some aspects of dependency chains and imports involved - if any other part of the system wants to import action creators from a duck, it will kind of drag along the reducer logic in the process. The reducers may not actually get imported elsewhere, but there's a dependency on that one file. If that doesn't bother you, feel free to use "ducks".

There's four approaches I can think of off the top of my head to have both modules' reducers respond to the same actions:

1. Have Module A import action constants from Module B's "duck" directly
2. Define the action constants in separate files so that Module A does `import * as types from "moduleB/constants"`.
3. Duplicate the action type strings so that Module A isn't actually importing anything from Module B
4. Use a separate side effect library like a saga or an observable to glue together the behavior in some way.

I personally would suggest not worrying about cross-"module" imports or dependencies too much, unless you're *really* trying to keep different parts of the application completely and entirely encapsulated from everything else.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I have not found any good documentation to handle cross module communication in React-Redux.  I prefer keeping my modules isolated, but currently do not have a way to do that.  Currently I am using method 1, where I import actions from B directly into A.  I was in fact contemplating about creating a observable or pub sub module which handles such interactions and helps keep the modules independent of each other.  I will look into all the other ways you have mentioned here and try to see if any of them are best fit my needs!

Comment: You may be over-thinking the "cross-module communication" aspect a bit.  In general, it should probably involve dispatching actions that another module might care about, either by resulting in state updates, or triggering saga/observable behavior.  You might want to read through https://medium.com/@totaldis/redux-saga-in-action-s-f7d11cffa35a for some examples.

Answer (score 0):

Views are controlled by the store, right?

So when an action happens in either A or B just dispatch an action that will update the view in B or A respectively.

```
{
  currentAView: 'product1'
}
```

Click the button in B view. Action dispatched `showProduct(product2)`.

```
{
  currentAView: 'product2'
}
```